# Julia: Overriding function of abstract type not getting called

Tags: julia

I am developing a Provider package in Julia which would be used by multiple Consumer packages. Below is a minimal example of the Project structure for the `Provider` package and a sample Consumer package called `Consumer_A` to reproduce the issue :

[image]

The file generic.jl in the Provider package defines an abstract type `AbstractDataLoader` with a function `load_data`. This function is overridden in the concrete type `CustomDataLoader` defined in the file custom_implementation.jl in the Consumer_A package as shown below:

generic.jl :

```
export DataProcessor, process_data

abstract type AbstractDataLoader end
function load_data(data_loader::AbstractDataLoader)
    error("No load_data function defined for $(typeof(data_loader))")
end

struct DataProcessor end
function process_data(data_loader::AbstractDataLoader)
    data = load_data(data_loader)
    println("do some processing after loading data: $data")
end
```

custom_implementation.jl :

```
import Provider

export CustomDataLoader, load_data

struct CustomDataLoader <: Provider.AbstractDataLoader  end
function load_data(data_loader::CustomDataLoader)
    return "sample data"
end
```

The main.jl file has a `main` function which instantiates the concrete type and calls a method `process_data` that in turn should ideally call the overriding function:

```
using Provider

export main

function main()
    data_loader = CustomDataLoader()
    data_processor = DataProcessor()
    process_data(data_loader)
end
```

But instead, on running `main()` I get the error "No load_data function defined for CustomDataLoader" that is raised in the generic.jl `load_data` function. How do I ensure that the overriding concrete type function gets called in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In custom_implementation.jl , I tried replacing `function load_data` with `function Provider.load_data` because I was using the statement `import Provider` instead of `using Provider` as I wanted to override the definition. With this change, it works fine and the overriding function gets called!

The updated custom_implementation.jl is now:

```
import Provider

export CustomDataLoader, load_data

struct CustomDataLoader <: Provider.AbstractDataLoader  end
function Provider.load_data(data_loader::CustomDataLoader)
    return "sample data"
end
```